# Change century for yy year in Date.strptime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a string in the form `"mmddyy"` (e.g.: `"011467"`). This string represents date of birth. Now, I would like to parse it to a Date object, so I have used:

```
Date.strptime('011467', '%m%d%y')
```

However, this produced `14th January 2067`, instead of the expected `14th January 1967`. How do I change the century for strptime? The problem is with dates up to today, which can have the form `"071717"`, in which case the `17th July 2017` is a valid date. (In our application, we do not expect people older than 100 years - yet, if such person would occur there, he/she could easily change the birth year).

Answer (score 1):

[`Date.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) does not accept a format, [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) does.

Also, you need to manually adjust the year.

```
%w|011467 011417|.map do |s|
  Date.strptime(
    s.gsub(/\d{2}\z/) do |m|
      (m.to_i <= Date.today.year.to_s[/\d{2}\z/].to_i ? "20" : "19") << m
    end, '%m%d%Y')
}
#⇒ [
#   [0] #<Date: 1967-01-14 ((2439505j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#   [1] #<Date: 2017-01-14 ((2457768j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# ]
```